# Добавление строки только при создании файла

Tags: python

Есть код который работает в бесконечном цикле и каждый день создаёт новый файл, нужно что бы при создании файла писалась первая строка и при повторном запуске кода в один день он видел что файл с датой этого дня в названии уже есть и не добавлял первую строку а лишь дописывал остальные.

Пытался сделать добавлением аргумента 'x' но при созданом файле лишь выдаёт ошибку что файл существует

```
import time

while True:
    file_way = '{}.csv'.format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-d'))
    file = open(file_way, 'x')
    file.write("test1\n") //первая строка которая долна писаться лишь единожды
    file.close()
    file = open(file_way, 'a')
    file.write('test2\n') //тут по идеи поступаюие данные которые каждый раз разные
    file.close()
```

Может можно сделать внутри цикла какую-то прверку на существование файла? Вроде "если файл не существует то создать файл и написать первую строку" и возврат в основной цикл, но не знаю как задать это условие на существование файла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таких ситуациях надо просто использовать поиск, например, написав: "python проверка наличия файла". Сразу увидите, что вам нужно использовать `os.path.isfile`.
На  всякий случай, находим её описание [тут](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-os-path-python/funktsija-isfile-modulja-os-path/#:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%3A,%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20os). и читаем, а потом вносим в код небольшие изменения.
Проверьте, как работает, исправьте, где нужно.

```
import time
# Добавили импорт
import os.path


while True:
    file_way = '{}.csv'.format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-d'))
    # Проверяем, и если файла нет, то пишем первый раз
    if not os.path.isfile(file_way):
        file = open(file_way, 'x')
        file.write("test1\n") //первая строка, которая должна писаться лишь единожды
        file.close()
    # Иначе (файл есть) - пишем новые данные.
    else:
        file = open(file_way, 'a')
        file.write('test2\n') //тут, по идее, поступают данные которые каждый раз разные
        file.close()
```

Comment: думаю, что вы знакомы с [этим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/209304)

Comment: @Dmitry, да, я знаком с принципом. И прицип говорит, чтобы людей не отфутболивали, а давали ответы на SO (что я и сделал), приведя код. Но он совершенно не запрещает в дополнение ещё и пояснять людям, как они могли найти ответ самостоятельно, чтобы они могли развиваться. А вот минусование верного ответа, которое вы сделали, вряд ли соответствует правилам.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что вы видите, кто поставил минус. Ставить минус не запрещено правилами, даже на верный ответ, если он не является полезным, оскорбителен или еще множество причин. Я практикую минусы для ответов на учебные вопросы (откровенно учебные). Это не ваш случай

Comment: Разумеется, не вижу. Просто на интервале в несколько часов без реакции на вопрос я получил минус (без каких-либо пояснений) и ваш достаточно странный комментарий с разницей в 3 минуты. Корреляция очень высокая.

Answer (score 5):

Можно использовать конструкцию `try... except`:

```
import time

while True:
    file_way = '{}.csv'.format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-d'))
    try:
        file = open(file_way, 'x')
        file.write("test1\n") //первая строка которая долна писаться лишь единожды
        file.close()
    except FileExistsError:
        file = open(file_way, 'a')
        file.write('test2\n') //тут по идеи поступаюие данные которые каждый раз разные
        file.close()
```

И еще я бы советовал использовать менеджер `with`:

```
import time

while True:
    file_way = '{}.csv'.format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-d'))
    try:
        with open(file_way, 'x') as file:
            file.write("test1\n")
    except FileExistsError:
        with open(file_way, 'a') as file:
            file.write('test2\n')
```

И еще одно замечание. Если вы будете без задрежки пытаться открыть/закрыть файлы - система может этому не обрадоваться. Советую поставить задержку `time.sleep(ms)` в конце цикла, где `ms` - время в милисекундах, которое для вас не критично.